# Find Sum of Current and Previous month value when immediate previous month data is missing

Tags: oracle, hive, impala

I have a source table with employee account details for each month, date is String type (yyyyMMdd). Trying to find the sum of current month values and previous month values for each account.

used the below query but it is returning asset_previous as month before if the previous month data is not available.

```
SELECT
    x.*,
    LAG(current_month_sum, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY account ORDER BY adate) previous_month_sum  
FROM (
    SELECT adate, account, SUM(amount) current_month_sum  
    FROM employee_assets
    GROUP BY adate, account
) x
ORDER BY adate DESC
```

for example: We don't have input data for 20181231 for account 123, so asset_prev for month January should be 0, but query is returning 500 (which is amount for November'2018)
Input data:

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|  adate    | account     | division  |  amount  |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190331  | 123         | AB0       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190331  | 123         | AB1       | 110      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190331  | 123         | AB2       | 120      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190228  | 123         | AB4       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190228  | 123         | AB1       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190228  | 123         | AB2       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20190131  | 123         | AB0       | 100      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| 20181130  | 123         | ABX       | 500      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

Query Output:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|  adate    | account     | current_month_sum  |  previous_month_sum  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190331  | 123         | 330                | 300                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190228  | 123         | 300                | 100                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190131  | 123         | 100                | 500                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20191131  | 123         | 500                | 0                    |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|  adate    | account     | current_month_sum  |  previous_month_sum  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190331  | 123         | 330                | 300                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190228  | 123         | 300                | 100                  |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20190131  | 123         | 100                | 0                    |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| 20191131  | 123         | 500                | 0                    |
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: What is your actual database?  The tags you have added are incompatible with each other.

Answer (score 2):

try below Query

```
select adate ,CURRENT_AMT ,
     case when mon-1<>PREVIDATE then 0 else PREVI end as PREVIOUS_AMT
    from(
    select adate, 
    sum(amount) CURRENT_AMT,
    lag(sum(amount),1,0)over(order by adate)PREVI,
    (cast (substr(adate,5,2) as integer)) mon,
    lag(cast (substr(adate,5,2) as integer),1,1) over(order by adate)PREVIDATE
    from  stack_demo_q group by adate order by adate
    )
```

Comment: This query is working in case of missing month data, it is assigning "0" as previous_value but for January of each year it is treating previous month as not available. for example I have data for 201812 but in month of 201901 it is assigning previous_value as "0".Same case with 201801 month data. Please suggest how this can be handled in same query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select adate,amt as current_month_sum,case when mon=1 and (monthh-1=monh) then PREVI when  mon-1<>PREVIDATE then 0   else PREVI end as previous_month_sum
from(
select adate,sum(amount) amt,lag(sum(amount),1,0)over(order by adate)PREVI,
(cast (substr(adate,5,2) as integer)) mon,
lag(cast (substr(adate,5,2) as integer),1,1) over(order by adate)PREVIDATE,
lag (cast (substr(adate,1,4) as integer),1,1) over (order by adate) monh,
(cast (substr(adate,1,4) as integer)) as monthh
from  stack_demo_q group by adate order by adate);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This query is returning me "0" for previous_month_sum even if I have data for previous month.
Current month value is correct for all months but it is putting "0" as previous_month_sum for all months.
Please help in updating this query.

Comment: select adate,amt as current_month_sum,case when mon-1<>PREVIDATE then 0 else PREVI end as previous_month_sum
from(
select adate,sum(amount) amt,lag(sum(amount),1,0)over(order by adate)PREVI,
(cast (substr(adate,5,2) as integer)) mon,
lag(cast (substr(adate,5,2) as integer),1,1) over(order by adate)PREVIDATE
from  employee_assets group by adate order by adate)

Comment: @ASaraf Check now updated query pasted in above section.

Comment: This query is working in case of missing month data, it is assigning "0" as previous_value but for January of each year it is treating previous month as not available.
for example I have data for 201812 but in month of 201901 it is assigning previous_value as "0"..Same case with 201801 month data.
Please suggest how this can be handled in same query.

Comment: @ASaraf Check now  updated query pasted in above section of the answers.

Comment: I have used the updated query but now this query is returning "o" as previous month_value for all months :(

Comment: @ASaraf suppose ( date 20181230  and amount 100 ) then ( 20190130 and amount 200 ) i.e 20181230 = 0 and 20190130  =300 (sum of prevoius + current month )...
is it the output like that u want

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range` clause but with `sum` analytical function as following:

**-- updated --**

```
SQL> WITH employee_assets  (adate    , account     , division  ,  amount )
  2  AS
  3  (SELECT  TO_DATE('20190331','YYYYMMDD')  , 123         , 'AB0'       , 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT  TO_DATE('20190331','YYYYMMDD')  , 123         , 'AB1'       , 110 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT  TO_DATE('20190331','YYYYMMDD')  , 123         , 'AB2'       , 120 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT  TO_DATE('20190228','YYYYMMDD')  , 123         , 'AB4'       , 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT  TO_DATE('20190228','YYYYMMDD')  , 123         , 'AB1'       , 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT  TO_DATE('20190228','YYYYMMDD')  , 123         , 'AB2'       , 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  9  SELECT  TO_DATE('20190131','YYYYMMDD')  , 123         , 'AB0'       , 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 10  SELECT  TO_DATE('20181130','YYYYMMDD')  , 123         , 'ABX'       , 500 FROM DUAL)
 11  SELECT
 12      X.ADATE, X.ACCOUNT, X.CURRENT_MONTH_SUM,
 13      SUM(CURRENT_MONTH_SUM) OVER(
 14          PARTITION BY ACCOUNT
 15          ORDER BY
 16              AMONTH
 17          RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
 18      ) PREVIOUS_MONTH_SUM
 19  FROM
 20      (
 21          SELECT
 22              ADATE,
 23              ACCOUNT,
 24              SUM(AMOUNT) CURRENT_MONTH_SUM,
 25              TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADATE, 'YYYYMM')) AS AMONTH
 26          FROM
 27              EMPLOYEE_ASSETS
 28          GROUP BY
 29              ADATE,
 30              ACCOUNT
 31      ) X
 32  ORDER BY
 33      ADATE DESC
 34  ;

ADATE        ACCOUNT CURRENT_MONTH_SUM PREVIOUS_MONTH_SUM
--------- ---------- ----------------- ------------------
31-MAR-19        123               330                300
28-FEB-19        123               300                100
31-JAN-19        123               100
30-NOV-18        123               500

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This query is not returning "0" as previous_value if previous month data is missing.
for example - I have data in 20190630 and 20190531 data is missing. I am getting 20190430 month sum as previous_value in month of June 20190630

Comment: Updated the answer according to the requirement, Please check

Comment: I ran the same query in impala and It gave me "AnalysisException: RANGE is only supported with both the lower and upper bounds UNBOUNDED or one UNBOUNDED and the other CURRENT ROW."
I changes "range" to "rows" and re ran the query. It returned me results but if month-1 is missing then it is returning me month-2 value as previous month sum.